# Rx/Tx login issue

Tags: pi-3

I tried to ommunication between TX/RX to make some test and I received the following response:

```
raspberrypi login : Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 raspberrypi ttyAMA0
```

Can you please explain to me the problem and if possible how to solve it :). Thanks a lot

The python code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import time

ser=serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600)

While True:
    ser.write('x')
    received=ser.readline().strip()
    print(received)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Have you disabled the "serial console" in `sudo raspi-config` or with the preferences GUI dialog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SIM900A with Raspberry Pi 3 Weird Error and Behaviour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107553/sim900a-with-raspberry-pi-3-weird-error-and-behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

It's no a problem.  You can log in via the serial link.

If you don't want this behaviour then disable  it by using the advanced options of `raspi-config`.

`sudo raspi-config`

Comment: Thanks Joan. How to login via the serial link ?!

Comment: I thought you were complaining about the message.  I've told you what to do to stop that message. Run `sudo raspi-config` and disable serial login in the advanced options.

Comment: I disabled the login. however after launching the script an error appeared (couldn't sopen serial /dev/ttyAMA0). Anything i should configure it differently ?

Comment: @Nassim That sounds like a new question.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/ttyAMA0` is connected to Bluetooth (unless you change it).

See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)